# How to properly reload a PKCS11 KeyStore

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#11

I would like to test my keys in the PKCS11 keystore. But it seems my keystore is not updated when an external process is adding or deleting keys in the store.

The second time I print the aliases does not include new aliases which are inserted in between.

How can I properly reload the keystore?

```
public class KeyStoreTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, LoginException{

        // initialize keystore
        InputStream is = CheckUploadScript.class.getResourceAsStream("pkcs11-hsm.config");
        AuthProvider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(is);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
        ks.load(null, "0000".toCharArray());

        // print all aliases
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        for (String key : Collections.list(aliases))
            System.out.println("alias: " + key);

        // upload or delete keys with external tool here


        // print all aliases again (does not change)
        ks.load(null, "0000".toCharArray());
        aliases = ks.aliases();
        for (String key : Collections.list(aliases))
            System.out.println("alias: " + key);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I followed the instructions from the PKCS11 reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html

```
char[] pin = ...; 
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
ks.load(null, pin);
```

For my understanding, when using a PKCS11 keystore the security provider handles storing and loading of keys. Therefore I don't have to specify an InputStream when I load the keystore.

Comment: Sorry but how could a keystore be modified by another process if the keystore is new initialized with `ks.load(null, "0000".toCharArray());` and never stored to the disk? It seems to me that your keystore only exists in your heap.

Comment: I use a HSM simulator which stores the keys somewhere on the disk. The HSM simulator provides command line tools to manipulate the keystore. I can also store new keys with the above implementation `ks.setEntry` and the keys are immediately available through the command line tools. Only if I load the keystore in java and upload new keys with the command line tools, the keystore in java does not pick up the new keys.

Answer (score 1):

For PKCS11 truststores, the InputStream argument to KeyStore.getInstance must (perhaps should) be null. It is not used, so there is no file to close.

Answer (score 0):

try loading it explicit

`KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
keyStore.load(trustStore, trustStorePassword);
trustStore.close();`